# Problem with multiple languages in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, languages, babel, spanish

I'm new here. I'm typing my Thesis and I'm using two languages (Spanish, English). This is my code:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,letterpaper,titlepage,12pt,oneside,spanish,final]{report_eie}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
.
.
\usepackage{indentfirst} %(Because I have declared a new language, english)
\usepackage[apaciteclassic]{apacite}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
.
.
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{spanish} 
.
.
.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCIAS}
\let\oldbibsection\bibsection
\bibliography{biblioteca} 
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

All works but the bibliography is showed in English (for example, the ordinal numbers are showed "Nth", instead of Nª, "and" instead of "y", etc). If I type `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` and delete `\selectlanguage{spanish}` the bibliography is showed in Spanish. What I can do? I need to use both languages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I would like to point out the combination `\documentclass[spanish]{..}` with `\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}` doesn't make Spanish the main language (the second `spanish` is just ignored). If you want to set `spanish` as the main language, you must upgrade to babel 3.9 and use `\usepackage[english,main=spanish]{babel}` or remove `spanish` from the global options.

Comment: @JavierBezos at least all names and hyphenation are changed to Spanish, am I wrong?

Comment: I just removed `spanish` from the line `\documentclass[hidelinks,letterpaper,titlepage,12pt,oneside,spanish,final]{report_eie}` and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks to `\selectlanguage{spanish}`. Without it, the language is `english`. On the other hand, `spanish` makes some additional changes when it's the main language.

Comment: @JavierBezos I'm still using `babel v3.8m` so I don't know of version `3.9`. And using `\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}` I get all names and hyphenation in Italian, without the need to specify `\selectlanguage{italian}`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want Spanish entries in the bibliography to be handled like they should be in Spanish, and English entries similarly in English?

If this is the case, You'll have to use a `bibtex` style that is capable of switching the language for each entry in the bibliography.

`biblatex` package provides such a functionality, by using an additional field <strike>'`hyphenation`'</strike> `langid` for each `bibtex` database entry. This field indicates the language the entry should be presented in, thus allowing `biblatex` to put each entry in a correct `babel` language environment. Then you'll get each entry in the bibliography to behave its correctly.

Comment: You might be a bit careful here, bibtex and biblatex aren't really related much besides using the same data format. Your wording can be read as is biblatex is a bibtex style, which it isn't